# Angular 8 cdk get index

Tags: angular, angular-cdk

I am working on Angular CDK drag and drop, when I am dropping an item into the list I can get index from previous list and the new index it has, how I will get the index of the item above which the handle is dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my understanding is right, you need the index of item that is below the dropped item.

For that you can use

for index of below item.

```
belowItemIndex=currentIndex+1;
```

for Index of above item

```
aboveItemIndex=currentIndex-1;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: is there a way I can replace items? instead of appending

Comment: yeah, you can just pop/remove the object which you want to remove from array in ts file